# JB Media codec decoder issue

Tags: android, video, media, codec, decoding

I am using JB's Hardware Media Codec . I am trying to encode a video and decode it and display using the codecs (in video/avc format)...

I am using two buttons to "start" and "stop" the video rendering. The first time, when I render the video it is displayed correctly. When I start the video second time, it is not getting displayed and throws the following error:

"NOT in AVI Mode"

I copy paste the code snippets for the start and Stop button.

```
     public void Stop(){
    try {
        //stopping the decoder alone
        decoderMediaCodec.flush();
        decoderMediaCodec.stop();
        decoderMediaCodec.release();
         //Tried with various combination of flush(), stop() and release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void Start(Surface view){
    try {
        decoderMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);//Initialize the decoder again
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mime, mWidth, mHeight);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, framerate);
        decoderMediaCodec.configure(format, view, null, 0);
        decoderMediaCodec.start();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Kindly help me with the video rendering.

Note : data received in decoder is valid... data is checked using the beyond compare tool

I am getting -1 for outputBufferIndex

```
    int outputBufferIndex = decoderMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
```

In logs i get

E/(  271):

E/(  271):not in avi mode

E/(  271):

E/(  271):  not in avi mode

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could share more logs when you encounter the issue. From the description of your issue, could you confirm that the `Surface` being passed for your 2nd `Start` call is a valid handle?

If you can rebuild android, probably enabling log traces in `Mediacodec.cpp` would be helpful, specifically `Mediacodec::setNativeWindow` method.

P.S: For a decoder, why are I-frame interval, bitrate and framerate being set?